# Change Circle orientation based on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirment where I need a data set to show in circles. each circle should be connect to other circle via an arrow direction to right. so when the circles are started from left to right when it reach to end of the screen the next circle should come to next row at right side and continue the direction from there.

so here is a screenshot. This is what I wanted. if its in a larger screen of course it will display all the circles horizontally.

[image]

```css
.circle-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 1</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 2</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 3</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 4</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 5</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 6</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 7</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <font color="red"><strong>Item 8</strong></font>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I achieved
[image]

Note that HTML part is hardcoded just for testing purpose. It will go inside a forloop in production. Normally 20 items will be there.
What can I do to get my output?
This is for a asp.net core project.

Comment: Basically the same issue, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091822/flexbox-alternate-row-and-row-reverse-according-to-rows-number

Comment: 1) check available width and calculate how many objects will fit one row. 2) Fill rows with runtime generated code. 3) Use Flex and each row change flex-direction (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)